# A system of diferential equations solved by Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, laplace-transform

I have this system of diferential equations

$$ \begin{cases} q'+q+i=50e^{-t}u_1(t) \\ i'+i-q=0 \end{cases}$$

$q(0)=i(0)=0$

** $ u_1(t) $ is the Heaviside step function

**Solution**

Rewriting:
$$ \begin{cases} q'=50e^{-t}u_1(t)-q-i \\ i'=q-i \end{cases} $$
Laplace transform:

$$ \begin{cases} sL[q]-q(0)=\frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{s+1}-L[q]-L[i] \\ sL[i]-s(0)=L[q]-L[i] \end{cases} $$

Rewriting:

$$ \begin{cases} (s+1)L[q]+L[i]=\frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{s+1} \\ -L[q]+(s+1)L[i]=0 \end{cases} $$

By Cramer:

$$L[q]=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{cc}\frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{s+1} & 1 \\ 0 & (s+1) \end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{cc}(s+1) & 1 \\ -1 & (s+1) \end{array}\right|}=\frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{(s+1)^2+1}$$
so $\qquad \qquad q=50L^{-1}[\frac{e^{-(s+1)}}{(s+1)^2+1}]$

$$ $$

$$L[i]=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{cc}(s+1) & \frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{s+1}\\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{cc}(s+1) & 1 \\ -1 & (s+1) \end{array}\right|}=\frac{\frac{50e^{-(s+1)}}{s+1}}{(s+1)^2+1}$$
so $\qquad \qquad i=50L^{-1}[\frac{e^{-(s+1)}}{(s+1)((s+1)^2+1}]$

$$ $$

I don't have any idea how I can solve this inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is somewhat easier to first obtain an equation for $i$ :
\begin{equation*}
i^{\prime \prime }+2i^{\prime }+i=50e^{-t},\;t\geqslant 0
\end{equation*}
Then, with
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=&\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [izt]i(t),\;Imz>0, \\
i(t) &=&\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{\Gamma }dz\exp [-izt]f(z)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\Gamma $ is a straight line above and parallel to the real axis, You
obtain, using your initial conditions, which imply that also $i^{\prime
}(0)=0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z) &=&-50i(z+i)^{-3} \\
i(t) &=&-50i\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{\Gamma }dz\exp [-izt](z+i)^{-3}
\end{eqnarray*}
from which $i(t)$ follows in the usual way.
By the way, you can also proceed by setting $i(t)=g(t)\exp [-t]$ which
leaves you with
\begin{equation*}
g^{\prime \prime }(t)+g^{\prime }(t)-g(t)=50
\end{equation*}
that can also be handled by standard methods.